# Running ./autogen.sh with bash -c fails

Tags: mingw, autoconf, msys2, appveyor

I port autoconf project from Linux to Windows and when I invoke `autogen.sh` with `bash`, it fails on `dirname $0`:

```
C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -c "./autogen.sh"
/usr/bin/dirname: missing operand
Try '/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.
Command exited with code 1
```

Failing build with `sh` - https://ci.appveyor.com/project/techtonik/augeas/build/1.0.5
Failing build with `bash` - https://ci.appveyor.com/project/techtonik/augeas/build/1.0.6
And here is the source code - https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/blob/master/autogen.sh

Comment: Can you please create a repro in public repository?

Comment: @ilyaf see updated links

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I'm hitting a similar problem.